# RewriteRule does not work for HTTPS pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have recently moved from HTTP to HTTPS and there are some specific pages that need to be redirected. The http pages redirect but the https pages do not. I have created a test environment and a simplified htaccess with just two simple rewrites – one specifically for HTTP and one specifically for HTTPS. The htaccess file is in the test folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^test1.html$ https://www.example.com/test/test1new.html? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^test1.html$ https://www.example.com/test/test1new.html? [L,R=301]
```

Here's what happens:
http://www.example.com/test/test1.html  =>  redirected to:  https://www.example.com/test/test1new.html

The https test1 page is not redirected.

So HTTP works and HTTPS does not. For some reason, https pages cannot be redirected. I have performed the same tests on two other hosts and I always get the same thing. Is there a reason https redirects are being ignored? What can be done to make this work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove the space in `https://www.example.com /test/test1new.html?`. And the question mark at the end...

Comment: There is no space (sorry, it was mistakenly added above when I changed to example.com, but I have since edited my question). Removing the question mark doesn't help.